# How to set start value for a column which is autoincrement in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android application in which i have to get the autoincrement value from a table and display that value in an activity for that i have choosen sqlite database in that i have created a table named bill in which i have set the columns but i want to set an start value for the autoincrement column suppose if i set the start value as 1000 then the first record should be 1000 and then it should incremented by 1.

```
String CREATE_BILL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + BILL_LABELS + "("
            + BILL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + BILL_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + BILL_FARMERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + BILL_MOBILENO + " NUMERIC,"
            + BILL_PRODUCTTYPE + " TEXT,"
            + BILL_PRODUCTNO + " NUMERIC,"
            + BILL_PRODUCTCOST + " NUMERIC,"
            + BILL_TOTALAMOUNT + "NUMERIC" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BILL_TABLE);
```

can anyone tell me how i can achieve it in sqlite i have very little knowledge in sqlite database.

Comment: what do you need it for?

Comment: to show the next billno

Comment: i dont get it, keys / ids are for referencing rows (possibly in other tables), not for presentation purposes

Comment: in some application they have given to option to show the next bill no from sqlite database so for that what would they have done

Comment: and whats the difference if it starts from 0 or 1000?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = 1000 WHERE name = 'BILL_LABELS'
```

which will start the autoincrement field from 1001.

Comment: whether i have to use this update statement at the time of insertion

Comment: after creating the table,run this query

Comment: i have used the update query below the create statement but it doesn't show me the value 1000 when i run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET BILL_ID = 1000 WHERE name = 'BILL_LABELS'
```

It will start the auto-increment field from 1001.